# Title: Unpredictable "You Win" / "You Lose" Outcome in Tic Tac Toe Game

Tags: javascript, html, css, tic-tac-toe

I'm looking for guidance on how to approach debugging this issue and ensuring that the displayed message accurately reflects the game's outcome.

What I've Tried:

I've reviewed my code for any logical errors that could lead to this discrepancy between the game's outcome and the displayed message. I've also tested the game extensively to reproduce the issue, but it remains sporadic.

Request for Help:

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```js
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.boxes');


let arr = Array.from(boxes)

console.log(arr);

let pop = document.getElementById("pop")

let tossing = document.getElementById("tossing")

let tosser = document.getElementById("tosser")

let toss1 = document.getElementById("toss1")

let tossing1 = document.getElementById("tossing1")

let last = document.getElementById("last")

let laster = document.getElementById("laster")

setTimeout(() => {

  pop.classList.add("popup")

}, 3000)

let botTurn = ""

let choosedToss = "";

let count = 0;

gameWon = false;

let stat = "";

boxes.forEach(box => {

  box.addEventListener('click', function() {

    tosswinner.call(this);

  });

});

async function turner() {

  if (choosedToss === botTurn) {

    let selected = arr[

      Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];

    setTimeout(() => {

      if (selected.innerHTML == "") {

        setTimeout(() => {

          selected.innerHTML = 'O'

          win();

        }, 200)

        count++;

      } else {

        return turner()

      }

    }, 200)





  } else {

    let selected = arr[

      Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];

    setTimeout(() => {

      if (selected.innerHTML == "") {

        setTimeout(() => {

          selected.innerHTML = 'X'

          win();

        }, 200)

        count++;

      } else {

        return turner()

      }

    }, 200)



  }



}

function tosswinner() {

  if (choosedToss === botTurn) {

    let box = this

    if (box.innerHTML === "") {

      box.innerHTML = "X";

      count++;

      win();

    }





  } else {

    box = this

    if (box.innerHTML === "") {

      box.innerHTML = "O";

      count++;

      win();

    }

  }

}

async function FinalFunc() {

  let Hulk = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    setTimeout(() => {

      toss1.classList.remove("open1")

      resolve(1)

    }, 2000);

  });

  const result = await Hulk;

  console.log(result);

}

async function R() {

  let THOR = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    setTimeout(() => {

      if (choosedToss == botTurn) {

        tossing1.innerHTML = "you won , first turn is yours";

      } else {

        tossing1.innerHTML = "you have losted , you will play next to the winner ";

      }

      tossing1.classList.add("text1")

      resolve("Thor");

    }, 1500);

  });

  const result = await THOR;

  console.log(result);

}

async function botTurns() {

  let TOSS = ["Heads", "Tail"];

  botTurn = TOSS[Math.floor(Math.random() * TOSS.length)];

  tossing1.innerHTML = `<h1>${botTurn}</h1>`

  tossing1.classList.add("text")

}

async function Messi() {

  let cap = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    setTimeout(() => {

      tossing1.classList.remove("load")

      botTurns()

      resolve(botTurn);

    }, 3000);

  });

  const result = await cap;

  console.log(result);

}

async function Message() {

  let stark = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    setTimeout(() => {

      tossing.classList.remove("load")

      tossing.innerHTML = `you choosed ${choosedToss} !`

      resolve(`you choosed ${choosedToss}`);

    }, 1000);

  });

  const result = await stark;

  console.log(result);

}

async function popdown() {

  let tony = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    setTimeout(() => {

      tosser.classList.remove("tosseropen")

      resolve("rate");

    }, 2000);

  });

  const result = await tony;

  console.log(result);

}

async function Heads() {

  choosedToss = "Heads"

  pop.classList.remove("popup");

  tosser.classList.add("tosseropen")

  await Message();

  await popdown();

  toss1.classList.add("open1")

  await Messi();

  await R();

  await FinalFunc()

  await firstTurner();

}

async function Tail() {

  choosedToss = "Tail"

  pop.classList.remove("popup");

  tosser.classList.add("tosseropen")

  await Message();

  await popdown();

  toss1.classList.add("open1")

  await Messi();

  await R();

  await FinalFunc();

  await firstTurner();

}

async function firstTurner() {

  if (choosedToss != botTurn && count === 0) {

    turner()

  }

}

function win() {

  if (gameWon) {

    return;

  } else {

    for (let i = 0; i < 9; i += 3) {

      if (arr[i].innerHTML !== "" && arr[i].innerHTML === arr[i + 1].innerHTML && arr[i].innerHTML === arr[i + 2].innerHTML) {

        setTimeout(() => {

          last.classList.add("lastopen")

        }, 2000)

        gameWon = true;

        gameWinner();

        return;

      }

    }



    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

      if (arr[i].innerHTML !== "" && arr[i].innerHTML === arr[i + 3].innerHTML && arr[i].innerHTML === arr[i + 6].innerHTML) {

        setTimeout(() => {

          last.classList.add("lastopen")

        }, 2000)

        gameWon = true;

        gameWinner();

        return;

      }

    }

    if (arr[0].innerHTML !== "" && arr[0].innerHTML === arr[4].innerHTML && arr[0].innerHTML === arr[8].innerHTML) {

      setTimeout(() => {

        last.classList.add("lastopen")

      }, 2000)

      gameWon = true;

      gameWinner();

      return;

    }

    if (arr[2].innerHTML !== "" && arr[2].innerHTML === arr[4].innerHTML && arr[2].innerHTML === arr[6].innerHTML) {

      setTimeout(() => {

        last.classList.add("lastopen")

      }, 2000)

      gameWon = true;

      gameWinner();

      return;

    }

    if (!gameWon && count === 9) {

      setTimeout(() => {

        last.classList.add("lastopen")

      }, 2000)

      gameWon = true;

      gameWinner();

      return;

    }

  }

}

function makeMove() {

  if (!gameWon) {

    win();

  }

}

function resetGame() {

  gameWon = false;

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    arr[i].innerHTML = "";

  }



  last.classList.remove("lastopen")

  console.log(gameWon);

}

function gameWinner() {

  if (gameWon) {

    if (choosedToss == botTurn) {

      if (count % 2 != 0) {

        laster.innerHTML = "You Win"

      } else if (count % 2 == 0) {

        setTimeout(() => {

          laster.innerHTML = "You Lose"

        }, 300)

      }

    } else if (gameWon) {

      if (choosedToss != botTurn) {

        if (count % 2 != 0) {

          laster.innerHTML = "You Lose"

        } else if (count % 2 == 0) {

          laster.innerHTML = "You Win"

        }

      }

    }

  } else if (!gameWon) {

    laster.innerHTML = "Draw"

  }

}

function Exit() {

  last.classList.remove("lastopen")
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  align-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#mainbox {
  width: 240px;
  height: 240px;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  right: 60px;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  background-color: white;
}

.boxes {
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
  background: skyblue;
  margin: 2px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#pop,
#tosser,
#toss1 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 280px;
  background: skyblue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 12.5%;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(0.01);
  transition: transform 0.4s, top 0.4s;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  border-radius: 20px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

#pop.popup,
#tosser.tosseropen,
#toss1.open1,
#last.lastopen {
  visibility: visible;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  transform: translate(0px, 100px) scale(1);
}

.head,
.last-head {
  width: 280px;
  height: 50px;
  background: darkblue;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: bolder;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
}

#para {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  Position:absolute;
  top:70px;
}

.toss {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  margin:0px 0px 7px 10px;
  background: royalblue;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#tossing {
  color: white;
  font-size: 27px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  margin-bottom: 38px;
}

.text1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  margin-bottom: 65px;
}

.load {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 5px black solid;
  border-top: 5px royalblue solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 80px;
  animation: SpinAnimate 1s linear 0s infinite normal;
}

@keyframes SpinAnimate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

#last {
  height: 240px;
  width: 280px;
  background: skyblue;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  left: 12.5%;
}

.last-head {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
}

.button {
  height: 50px;
  width: 280px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 170px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
}

.a {
  width: 125px;
}

#laster {
  height: 140px;
  width: 280px;
  font-size: 33px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!--

  This script places a badge on your repl's full-browser view back to your repl's cover

  page. Try various colors for the theme: dark, light, red, orange, yellow, lime, green,

  teal, blue, blurple, magenta, pink!

  -->

<div id="mainbox">

  <div class="boxes" onclick="tosswinner(this);turner();win();"></div>

  <div class="boxes" onclick="tosswinner(this);turner();win();"></div>

  <div class="boxes" onclick="tosswinner(this);turner();win();"></div>

  <div class="boxes" onclick="tosswinner(this);turner();win();"></div>

  <div class="boxes" onclick="tosswinner(this);turner();win();"></div>

  <div class="boxes" onclick="tosswinner(this);turner();win();"></div>

  <div class="boxes" onclick="tosswinner(this);turner();win();"></div>

  <div class="boxes" onclick="tosswinner(this);turner();win();"></div>

  <div class="boxes" onclick="tosswinner(this);turner();win();"></div>

</div>

<div id="pop">

  <div class="head">TOSS</div>

  <div id="para">HEADS OR TAILS ? </div>

  <br/>

  <div>

    <button class="toss" onclick="Heads()">HEADS</button>

    <button class="toss" onclick="Tail()">TAIL</button>

  </div>

</div>

<div id="tosser">

  <div class="head">CHOOSED</div>

  <div id="tossing" class="load"> </div>

</div>

<div id="toss1">

  <div class="head">TOSSING</div>

  <div id="tossing1" class="load">
    <div id="tosser">

    </div>

  </div>

</div>

<div id="last">

  <div class="last-head">WINNER</div>

  <div id="laster"></div>

  <br>

  <div class="button"> <button class="toss a" onclick="resetGame()">RESTART</button>

    <button class="toss" onclick="Exit()">EXIT</button>

  </div>

</div>



<!--<script src="https://replit.com/public/js/replit-badge-v2.js" theme="dark" position="bottom-right"></script>-->

<!--<script src="script.js"></script>-->
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! I think this is the longest question I've ever seen, and yet there are so few useful informations.. I really recommend you learn to use Code Snippets (the `<>` button when you wite a question/answer). I will edit the question for you, but it still lacks some things: what is the unpredictable outcome exactly? Do the game ends when it shouldn't? Is it the wrong winner who is displayed? Have you tried adding `console.log`s to track which function is called and how?

Comment: Converted to a snippet - gives error.   There may be a missing .js "replit.js" that appears to just add an irrelevant (to the question) badge.

Comment: Actuall the problem is that sometimes as I said one in 10 times there is a problem and. that is with the displaying of message sometimes it suddenly displays the message without even going on the correct conditions sometimes it give that I wins but in reality the bot wins and sometimes it gives that bot wins but this time I win

Comment: Some points to note: go with *either* onclick **or** event handlers, not both - your boxes call `tosswinner()` *twice*, which is the most likely cause of your issue.

Comment: One suggestion:  separate the game logic from the UI.   Specifically, don't do things like `if (...InnerHTML === '..')` - keep the game state in memory (eg in an array) then *push* the game state to the UI so that it *reflects* the game state rather than *is* the game state.

Comment: Please [edit] the question so that it runs (even if it doesn't "work" 100%) - specifically add the missing `boxes` variable.

Comment: Provide me some more details. To improve my coding skills as. I am a beginner I don,t  have very strong grasp on my own i am trying to learn it all on my own so please help me to know more give me more insights of my coding what I have done  Wrong each and everything that i should know                                        
                                                                help me community to become a good devloper

Comment: I made it "work" by adding `let boxes = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("boxes"))` as the first line. However many things go wrong: You can start to play before heads/tails pick and it messes the logic to the point it can freeze the game. You shouldn't test directly `innerHTML` values is they are not reliable, I can edit them directly from developper tools for example, whereas JS local variables cannot directly be edited (global variables can via the console, meaning you should wrap all your code in a function). There are lots of things to say, and sorry, SO is not a teaching forum

Comment: As your code *mostly* works, you should try posting to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/   First comments will be: format your code so it's readable (might be SO that added the extra blank lines) / don't use global variables / don't use `onclick=`

Comment: No @freedomn-m , broken code is [not ready for review](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) until it's fixed.

Comment: You don’t reset count after a game is won/lost.

Comment: @TobySpeight thanks for the clarification.  The suggestion was in response to the comment regarding "teach me what I'm doing wrong in general" (paraphrased from OP) and "SO is not a teaching forum" comments.